# SPARK SQL LEFT JOIN too many rows

Tags: sql, apache-spark

Using spark 1.6.1.

Have some strange situation: two tables: timeevents and apps both have key id - device, when I do:

select device from timeevents - number of records returned is 60865

select distince device from timeevents - number of records returned is 60865

select device from apps - records: 112071

select distinct device from apps - records: 112071

when I run:

> select apps.`*`, timeevents.`*` from apps LEFT OUTER JOIN timeevents ON
>   apps.device = timeevents.device

the number of records returned is 112073...

and I checked - in output - I have 2 additional lines with same device id...
am I doing something wrong??

I was expecting 112071 - just the number in apps table ...

EDIT: tried as suggested:

```
SELECT device FROM timeevents  GROUP BY device  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
return 0

SELECT device FROM apps GROUP BY device    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
return 0

SELECT device FROM timeevents  GROUP BY device  HAVING COUNT(1) < 2
return 60865

SELECT device FROM apps GROUP BY device    HAVING COUNT(1) < 2
return 112071
```

EDIT:
Sorry my fault - didn't noticed it in first place in timeevents device (as original RDD) was String, in apps was Long ... still doesn't explain behaviour but when I force them to be Long in both - no more additional mysterious rows. ufff...

Thanks for help!!

Comment: That device must have 2 app records. It has to be happening elsewhere as well, because you are getting an additional record from another device

Comment: I'm not the best in spark...but select device from timeevents group by device having count(1) > 1 should give you the device entry thats duplicated

Answer (score 3):

Your join is not one-to-one.  Look for duplicates in your `timeevents` table:

```
SELECT device
FROM timeevents
GROUP BY device
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```